# Create a special visual selection tool for Image

Tags: delphi, winapi, gdi, window-management

I want to create a special kind of selection, in which the image darkened and in part which user is selecting, the real Image is shown. You can see an Example:

[image: Example]

I found two approaches for implementing this:

1. Implementing a control which show the darkened image.
   When user drag an ellipse over this control, an ellipse copy the real image (Image which is NOT Darkened) into the control canvas.
   In this scenario When he/she try to Resize the ellipse to SMALLER SIZE, first the whole rectangular area of  ellipse darkened and then real image draw in the new Smaller Ellipse.
2. Same as Approach 1, but instead of drawing on the canvas of the control, we create a new control which show the real image. In this case, all messages send to the new control, SHOULD pass to the parent control. Because if user try to resize the ellipse to smaller size, WM_MOVE messages sent to this control, instead of the parent control.

Can please, someone show me the right direction for implementing this. I think that approach 1 is very hard to implement because it cause lot's of Flicker. Unless I implement a way to only repaint the changed part by InvalidateRect function.

Here is the code of the class TScreenEmul which is implemented by me, until now. It works but it has flicker.

```
unit ScreenEmul;

interface

uses Classes, Types, Windows, Messages, Graphics, Controls, SysUtils, Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

const
   PixelCountMax = 32768;

type
  PRGBTripleArray = ^TRGBTripleArray;
  TRGBTripleArray = array[0..PixelCountMax-1] of TRGBTriple;
  TScreenEmul = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    LastRect, DrawRect: TRect;
    DrawStart: TPoint;
    MouseDown: Boolean;

    Backup, Darken: TBitmap;
    FBitmap: TBitmap;

    procedure BitmapChange(Sender: TObject);

    procedure WMLButtonDown(var Message: TWMLButtonDown); message WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
    procedure WMMouseMove(var Message: TWMMouseMove); message WM_MOUSEMOVE;
    procedure WMLButtonUp(var Message: TWMLButtonUp); message WM_LBUTTONUP;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd ); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;

    procedure DarkenBitmap(B: TBitmap);
    procedure RestoreImage;

    procedure CalculateDrawRect(X, Y: Integer);
    procedure SetBitmap(const Value: TBitmap);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Bitmap: TBitmap read FBitmap write SetBitmap;
  end;

implementation

{ TScreenEmul }

function  AlphaBlend(Color1, Color2: TRGBTriple; Alpha: Byte): TRGBTriple; overload;
var
  rPrimary : Real; // Primary (Color1) Intensity
  rSecondary: Real;// Secondary (Color2) Intensity
begin
  rPrimary:=((Alpha+1)/$100);
  rSecondary:=(($100-Alpha)/$100);

  with Result do
  begin
    rgbtBlue := Trunc(Color1.rgbtBlue * rPrimary + Color2.rgbtBlue * rSecondary);
    rgbtGreen := Trunc(Color1.rgbtGreen * rPrimary + Color2.rgbtGreen * rSecondary);
    rgbtRed := Trunc(Color1.rgbtRed * rPrimary + Color2.rgbtRed * rSecondary);
  end;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.BitmapChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(Backup);
  Backup := TBitmap.Create;
  Backup.Assign(FBitmap);

  DarkenBitmap(FBitmap);

  Darken := TBitmap.Create;
  Darken.Assign(FBitmap);
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.CalculateDrawRect(X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if X >= DrawStart.X then
  begin
    if DrawRect.Left <> DrawStart.X then DrawRect.Left := DrawStart.X;
    DrawRect.Right := X
  end
  else
  begin
    if DrawRect.Right <> DrawStart.X then DrawRect.Right := DrawStart.X;
    DrawRect.Left := X;
  end;
  if Y >= DrawStart.Y then
  begin
    if DrawRect.Top <> DrawStart.Y then DrawRect.Top := DrawStart.Y;
    DrawRect.Bottom := Y;
  end
  else
  begin
    if DrawRect.Bottom <> DrawStart.Y then DrawRect.Bottom := DrawStart.Y;
    DrawRect.Top := Y;
  end;
end;

constructor TScreenEmul.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  MouseDown := False;
  FBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  FBitmap.OnChange := BitmapChange;

  DoubleBuffered := True;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.DarkenBitmap(B: TBitmap);
var
  I, J: Integer;
  Row: PRGBTripleArray;
  rgbBlack: tagRGBTRIPLE;
begin
  rgbBlack.rgbtBlue := 0; rgbBlack.rgbtGreen := 0; rgbBlack.rgbtRed := 0;

  for I := 0 to B.Height - 1 do
  begin
    Row := B.ScanLine[I];

    for J := 0 to B.Width - 1 do
      Row[J] := AlphaBlend(Row[J], rgbBlack, 150);
  end;
end;

destructor TScreenEmul.Destroy;
begin
  FBitmap.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.RestoreImage;
begin
  BitBlt(FBitmap.Canvas.Handle,
    LastRect.Left, LastRect.Top, RectWidth(LastRect), RectHeight(LastRect),
    Darken.Canvas.Handle, LastRect.Left, LastRect.Top, SRCCOPY);
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.SetBitmap(const Value: TBitmap);
begin
  FBitmap := Value;
  FBitmap.OnChange := BitmapChange;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := LResult(False);
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.WMLButtonDown(var Message: TWMLButtonDown);
begin
  MouseDown := True;

  with DrawRect do
  begin
    Left := Message.XPos;
    Top := Message.YPos;
    Right := Left;
    Bottom := Top;
  end;

  DrawStart.X := DrawRect.Top;
  DrawStart.Y := DrawRect.Left;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.WMLButtonUp(var Message: TWMLButtonUp);
begin
  MouseDown := False;
  RestoreImage;
  InvalidateRect(Self.Handle, DrawRect, False);
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.WMMouseMove(var Message: TWMMouseMove);
begin
  if not MouseDown then Exit;
  CalculateDrawRect(Message.XPos, Message.YPos);

  RestoreImage;

  BitBlt(
    FBitmap.Canvas.Handle,
    DrawRect.Left, DrawRect.Top, RectWidth(DrawRect), RectHeight(DrawRect),
    Backup.Canvas.Handle,
    DrawRect.Left, DrawRect.Top,
    SRCCOPY);

  InvalidateRect(Self.Handle, DrawRect, False);

  LastRect := DrawRect;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  B: TBitmap;
  Rct: TRect;
  X, Y: Integer;
  FullRepaint: Boolean;
begin
  inherited;

  FullRepaint := GetUpdateRect(Self.Handle, Rct, False);
  if not FullRepaint then
  begin
    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FBitmap);
  end
  else
  begin
    B := TBitmap.Create;
    B.SetSize(RectWidth(Rct), RectHeight(Rct));
    FBitmap.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, B.Width, B.Height), B.Canvas, Rct);

    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, B);
    FreeAndNil(B);
  end;
end;

end.
```

For using this class:

```
var
  ScreenEmul: TScreenEmul;
begin
  ScreenEmul := TScreenEmul.Create(Self);
  ScreenEmul.Parent := Self;
  ScreenEmul.Align := alClient;
  ScreenEmul.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('C:\img13.bmp');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem. I answer the question for the record:

1- WMEraseBkgnd should return True to prevent painting background. I mistakenly returned False.

2- I inherited the WMPaint method which is not correct. I also copy the updated Rect into new Bitmap and then draw the bitmap into canvas which was slow the painting process. Here is full fixed source code:

```
unit ScreenEmul;

interface

uses Classes, Types, Windows, Messages, Graphics, Controls, SysUtils, Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

const
   PixelCountMax = 32768;

type
  PRGBTripleArray = ^TRGBTripleArray;
  TRGBTripleArray = array[0..PixelCountMax-1] of TRGBTriple;
  TScreenEmul = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    LastRect, DrawRect: TRect;
    DrawStart: TPoint;
    MouseDown: Boolean;

    Backup, Darken: TBitmap;
    FBitmap: TBitmap;

    procedure BitmapChange(Sender: TObject);

    procedure WMLButtonDown(var Message: TWMLButtonDown); message WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
    procedure WMMouseMove(var Message: TWMMouseMove); message WM_MOUSEMOVE;
    procedure WMLButtonUp(var Message: TWMLButtonUp); message WM_LBUTTONUP;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;

    procedure DarkenBitmap(B: TBitmap);
    procedure RestoreImage;

    procedure CalculateDrawRect(X, Y: Integer);
    procedure SetBitmap(const Value: TBitmap);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Bitmap: TBitmap read FBitmap write SetBitmap;
  end;

implementation

{ TScreenEmul }

function  AlphaBlend(Color1, Color2: TRGBTriple; Alpha: Byte): TRGBTriple; overload;
var
  rPrimary : Real; // Primary (Color1) Intensity
  rSecondary: Real;// Secondary (Color2) Intensity
begin
  rPrimary:=((Alpha+1)/$100);
  rSecondary:=(($100-Alpha)/$100);

  with Result do
  begin
    rgbtBlue := Trunc(Color1.rgbtBlue * rPrimary + Color2.rgbtBlue * rSecondary);
    rgbtGreen := Trunc(Color1.rgbtGreen * rPrimary + Color2.rgbtGreen * rSecondary);
    rgbtRed := Trunc(Color1.rgbtRed * rPrimary + Color2.rgbtRed * rSecondary);
  end;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.BitmapChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(Backup);
  Backup := TBitmap.Create;
  Backup.Assign(FBitmap);

  DarkenBitmap(FBitmap);

  Darken := TBitmap.Create;
  Darken.Assign(FBitmap);
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.CalculateDrawRect(X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if X >= DrawStart.X then
  begin
    if DrawRect.Left <> DrawStart.X then DrawRect.Left := DrawStart.X;
    DrawRect.Right := X
  end
  else
  begin
    if DrawRect.Right <> DrawStart.X then DrawRect.Right := DrawStart.X;
    DrawRect.Left := X;
  end;
  if Y >= DrawStart.Y then
  begin
    if DrawRect.Top <> DrawStart.Y then DrawRect.Top := DrawStart.Y;
    DrawRect.Bottom := Y;
  end
  else
  begin
    if DrawRect.Bottom <> DrawStart.Y then DrawRect.Bottom := DrawStart.Y;
    DrawRect.Top := Y;
  end;
end;

constructor TScreenEmul.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  MouseDown := False;
  FBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  FBitmap.OnChange := BitmapChange;

  DoubleBuffered := True;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.DarkenBitmap(B: TBitmap);
var
  I, J: Integer;
  Row: PRGBTripleArray;
  rgbBlack: tagRGBTRIPLE;
begin
  rgbBlack.rgbtBlue := 0; rgbBlack.rgbtGreen := 0; rgbBlack.rgbtRed := 0;

  for I := 0 to B.Height - 1 do
  begin
    Row := B.ScanLine[I];

    for J := 0 to B.Width - 1 do
      Row[J] := AlphaBlend(Row[J], rgbBlack, 150);
  end;
end;

destructor TScreenEmul.Destroy;
begin
  FBitmap.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.RestoreImage;
begin
  BitBlt(FBitmap.Canvas.Handle,
    LastRect.Left, LastRect.Top, RectWidth(LastRect), RectHeight(LastRect),
    Darken.Canvas.Handle, LastRect.Left, LastRect.Top, SRCCOPY);
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.SetBitmap(const Value: TBitmap);
begin
  FBitmap := Value;
  FBitmap.OnChange := BitmapChange;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := LResult(True);
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.WMLButtonDown(var Message: TWMLButtonDown);
begin
  MouseDown := True;

  with DrawRect do
  begin
    Left := Message.XPos;
    Top := Message.YPos;
    Right := Left;
    Bottom := Top;
  end;

  DrawStart.X := DrawRect.Top;
  DrawStart.Y := DrawRect.Left;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.WMLButtonUp(var Message: TWMLButtonUp);
begin
  MouseDown := False;
  RestoreImage;
  InvalidateRect(Self.Handle, DrawRect, False);
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.WMMouseMove(var Message: TWMMouseMove);
begin
  if not MouseDown then Exit;
  CalculateDrawRect(Message.XPos, Message.YPos);

  RestoreImage;

  BitBlt(
    FBitmap.Canvas.Handle,
    DrawRect.Left, DrawRect.Top, RectWidth(DrawRect), RectHeight(DrawRect),
    Backup.Canvas.Handle,
    DrawRect.Left, DrawRect.Top,
    SRCCOPY);

  InvalidateRect(Self.Handle, DrawRect, False);

  LastRect := DrawRect;
end;

procedure TScreenEmul.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  Rct: TRect;
  FullRepaint: Boolean;
begin
  FullRepaint := GetUpdateRect(Self.Handle, Rct, False);
  if not FullRepaint then
    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FBitmap)
  else
    BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, Rct.Left, Rct.Top, RectWidth(Rct), RectHeight(Rct), FBitmap.Canvas.Handle, Rct.Left, Rct.Top, SRCCOPY);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done someting similar... here are extracts of my code (only one bitmap in memory):

1. Grab screen ...

   Type
         GrabScreen = (GTSCREEN);
         [...]

   ```
   procedure PGrabScreen(bm: TBitMap; gt : GrabScreen);
   var
     DestRect, SourceRect: TRect;
     h: THandle;
     hdcSrc : THandle;
     pt : TPoint;
   begin
     case(gt) of
      //...  
       GTSCREEN : h := GetDesktopWindow;
     end;
     if h <> 0 then
     begin
       try
         begin
             hdcSrc := GetWindowDC(h);
             GetWindowRect(h, SourceRect);
         end;
           bm.Width  := SourceRect.Right - SourceRect.Left;
           bm.Height := SourceRect.Bottom - SourceRect.Top;
           DestRect := Rect(0, 0, SourceRect.Right - SourceRect.Left, SourceRect.Bottom - SourceRect.Top);
             StretchBlt(bm.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, bm.Width,
               bm.Height, hdcSrc,
               0,0,SourceRect.Right - SourceRect.Left,
               SourceRect.Bottom - SourceRect.Top,
               SRCCOPY);
             DrawCursor(bm,SourceRect.Left, SourceRect.Top);
       finally
         ReleaseDC(0, hdcSrc);
       end;
     end;
   end;
   ```
2. Blur that bitmap once selection is initiated by mouse down (suggested code)

   ```
   procedure BitmapBlur(var theBitmap: TBitmap);
   var
     x, y: Integer;
     yLine,
     xLine: PByteArray;
   begin
     for y := 1 to theBitmap.Height -2 do begin
       yLine := theBitmap.ScanLine[y -1];
       xLine := theBitmap.ScanLine[y];
       for x := 1 to theBitmap.Width -2 do begin
         xLine^[x * 3] := (
           xLine^[x * 3 -3] + xLine^[x * 3 +3] +
           yLine^[x * 3 -3] + yLine^[x * 3 +3] +
           yLine^[x * 3] + xLine^[x * 3 -3] +
           xLine^[x * 3 +3] + xLine^[x * 3]) div 8;
         xLine^[x * 3 +1] := (
           xLine^[x * 3 -2] + xLine^[x * 3 +4] +
           yLine^[x * 3 -2] + yLine^[x * 3 +4] +
           yLine^[x * 3 +1] + xLine^[x * 3 -2] +
           xLine^[x * 3 +4] + xLine^[x * 3 +1]) div 8;
         xLine^[x * 3 +2] := (
           xLine^[x * 3 -1] + xLine^[x * 3 +5] +
           yLine^[x * 3 -1] + yLine^[x * 3 +5] +
           yLine^[x * 3 +2] + xLine^[x * 3 -1] +
           xLine^[x * 3 +5] + xLine^[x * 3 +2]) div 8;
       end;
     end;
   end;
   ```
3. Select area* on the blurred bitmap on screen (exemple:)

   procedure GrabSelectedArea(Sender: TObject);
   begin

   Grab(image1.Picture.Bitmap, GTSCREEN);
      bmp := Image1.Picture.Bitmap;
      image1.Width := image1.Picture.Bitmap.Width;
      image1.Height := image1.Picture.Bitmap.Height;
      DoSelect := true;
      end;
4. Doing so, reverse (offset) the blur effect for the selected area on the bitmap.

---

*Here the code i have for selection

```
procedure Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  DestRect, SourceRect : TRect;
begin

  if DoSelect then begin
    Image1.Canvas.Rectangle(SelX,SelY,SelX1,SelY1);   
    if X <= SelX then
    begin
      SelX1 := SelX;
      SelX := X;
    end
    else
      SelX1 := X;
    if Y <= SelY then
    begin
      SelY1 := SelY;
      SelY := Y;
    end
    else
      SelY1 := Y;
    Image1.Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmCopy;
    SourceRect := Rect(SelX,SelY,SelX1,SelY1);
    DestRect := Rect(0,0,SelX1-SelX,SelY1-SelY);
    Image1.Canvas.CopyRect(DestRect,Image1.Canvas,SourceRect);
    Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Height := SelY1-SelY;
    Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Width := SelX1-SelX;
    Image1.SetBounds(0,0,SelX1-SelX,SelY1-SelY);
    DoSelect := false;
    if FormIsFullScreen then
      RestoreForm;
  end;
end;


   procedure Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
   if DoSelect then begin
     SelX := X;
     SelY := Y;
     SelX1 := X;
     SelY1 := Y;
     with Image1.Canvas do
     begin                    // Options shown in comments
        Pen.Width := 1;      // 2; // use with solid pen style
        Pen.Style := psDashDotDot; // psSolid;
        Pen.Mode := pmNotXOR; // pmXor;
        Brush.Style := bsClear;
        Pen.Color := clBlue; // clYellow;
     end;
   end;
end;


procedure Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
   if DoSelect then begin
     if ssLeft in Shift then
     begin
      Image1.Canvas.Rectangle(SelX,SelY,SelX1,SelY1);
      SelX1 := X;
      SelY1 := Y;
      Image1.Canvas.Rectangle(SelX,SelY,SelX1,SelY1);
     end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: this is nice, but keep in mind that he needs help on the pseudo algorithm not the entire solution...

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code. But this is not what I want to achieve. I want to darkening the background image (which is easy) and show the real image (not darkened) as the user select. Please take a look to the example picture I've send. While user resizing the selection, the real image should shown and resized. I implement this mysel but it has flicker. I will send my code as an answer, so people here can guide me how to optimize my algorithm.

Comment: This is what i have done. The screen image (Get screen procedure) is blurred (or darkened) once the mouse is down to select an area. Doing so, the selected area on the image is turned back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to have a Bitmap into memory(hidden) which you manipulate so the "flicker" effect won't appear. Second you need to apply some darken algorithm on the bitmap the you display and copy the selection from original Bitmap to the visible Bitmap.

In other words:

1. OffsetBitmap(original bitmap) copy to visible Bitmap.
2. when selection occurs:

   1. apply darken effect to visible Bitmap
   2. copy the selected rectangle from OFFSETBITMAP to the visible bitmap so you will have your selection with original light intensity.

Hope this helps to some degree -- implementing this takes a bit of time which I don't have right now.

Comment: That will be to slow. He should keep THREE bitmaps in memory: A darkened version, the original version and a "workplace". When the user updates the selection he should:  1) Copy the darkened bitmap to the workplace.  2) Copy the selected part from the original bitmap to the workplace.  3) Copy the workplace to the canvas.

Comment: My image can be 1440 x 900 pixel or even 1920 x 1940 (Screen Resolutions). Maybe I should use InvalidateRect and paint only updated part of the image. But I do not know how this is possible exactly.

Comment: Maybe I should calculate updated part of the image and call InvalidateRect every time, user change the selection.

Comment: You do NOT NEED 3 bitmaps in memory just the original and the visible(which if it's big) you just show the visible part...

Comment: This is exactly my question. How I can only show re visible part? By Using InvalidateRect (Approach 1) or By using creating another control which show the real image (Approach 2)